# 2ND FLOOR WASHER LEAK PLEASE ADVISE

Tags: water, leak

My husband for some reason was helping by clearing out the drain hose (a chore I do monthly) and didn’t securely close it. I ran a load of laundry and water leaked all under the washer and dryer - which are on the second floor.
Downstairs, underneath where the washer is had pool of water, but no dripping ceiling or wet baseboard.
Do I need a plumber or something because somewhere, it is wet, which will likely mold right? I think insurance will not cover bc it was human error.
How did the water travel and what should I do? Please and Thank you

Comment: *clearing out the drain hose* Is that because of lint? Because if so, a far, far better solution is to have a [lint trap](https://amzn.to/3Oddfw6) catch the lint so that it doesn't go down the drain.

Comment: I've used washing machines for *multiple decades* and never had to clean the hose. Someone was being extra dumb and removed the lint trap, so now they can do even more work.
AFAIK, washing machines actually have multiple traps. One is easily accessible. One requires draining water and the manual recommends monthly cleaning (but I find that quarterly is fine). Having to remove the hose means that multiple filter systems are damaged/removed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you found the leak when the washer drained after the wash cycle, The water would have some soap in it, reducing the chance of mold.

If any water was cleaned up quickly and areas allowed to dry up, there is less a chance for mold.

Mold usually occurs where there was a longer term water issue, such as something dripping or weeping water over a longer period of time.

This being a one time issue and you getting the areas as dry as possible asap, I don't think there is a great chance of mold.  That said, should you feel that your peace of mind dictates that areas be opened to examine, give your insurance a call, or suck it up and foot the bill for remediation.

Comment: The water needs to sit around for quite a while before mold forms if the place was otherwise mold free.